# How can I use a group policy or similar to force specific folders on a share to have a different colour or icon?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

Please note I don't want to do this from the client side, it must be achieved only from the server side using a GP or something similar.

I would like the specified folders to either be a different colour or possible just a different icon.

For clarification, I want the client machines (Windows 7) to show the nominated folders in a different way when the user browses the share.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do understand that, assuming this is possible, if you do it via GPO you *are* doing it from the client side.

Comment: I think he meant the clients individually

Comment: I'm sure that's what he meant; but his phrasing of it made me suspect a gap in understanding.

Comment: I meant a solution that doesn't involve any physical visit to the client machines, SCCM deployment of a solution would be fine.